How can an audio signal with varying frequency be modulated using FM?
An audio signal can have varying frequency and amplitude and both are the part of the information. As I understand it, frequency modulation is a technique where the frequency of the carrier wave is varied according to the amplitude or intensity of the modulating signal. How does this work if under FM, the carrier wave only has the information about the intensity or the amplitude of the modulating signal, as in FM the carrier frequency is varied according to the intensity?
Someone had told me to use a voltage controlled oscillator(VCO,) but the question remain as VCOs also vary the frequency according to the intensity of the input signal. What if the input signal is also varying in frequency (of course inside a range?)
So specifically, how can an audio signal be modulated using FM?

I answered out of pity; a simple Google search will figure this one out... Research IS EXPECTED here on Stackexchange


VCOs also vary the frequency according to the intensity of the input signal. | Thats why it was suggested you use that. The quicker you change the input intensity, the quicker the frequency output changes


But VCO is only varying the frequency of the output signal only according to the intensity or amplitude of the input, then what will happen if the frequency of input is also varying ?

The quicker you change (i.e. increase the frequency of) the input intensity, the quicker the frequency output changes.

So the output frequency of VCOs are not just varied according to the input but also is varied according to the input frequency , right?

The audio signal is not modulated; the output is modulated by the audio.

You are separating the intensity and the frequency of the signal.  They are not separate.
The intensity varies, carrying the frequency components of the audio.
Here's a simple (slightly distorted) sine wave:

At every point along the X axis (time) the voltage (intensity) varies.
The peak to peak voltage is constant - this is what you have been thinking of as "intensity."
As you can see, however, the voltage itself is constantly varying.  The variation of the voltage carries the frequency content - the voltage varies at the frequency of the signal.
If you apply that signal to a voltage controlled oscillator, the output frequency of the oscillator will vary as the voltage varies.
The signal doesn't have to be a simple sine wave.  A voice signal contains many frequencies at the same time, but at any single point in time will only have a single voltage.
This is a look at the signal generated by a microphone when I say "aaaaaaa."

There is no single, simple frequency.  There is no simple "intensity."
You can still drive a voltage controlled oscillator with that signal and see a varying (frequency modulated) signal at the output.
The frequency referred to in "frequency modulation" is not the input frequency.  It is the output frequency.

When the input voltage is zero, then the output of the FM modulator is a fixed frequency. Example: 1 MHz.
When the input voltage is more than zero, then the output of the FM modulator is a higher frequency.  Example: 1.1 MHz.
When the input voltage is less than zero, then the output of the FM modulator is a lower frequency.  Example: 0.9 MHz.

The output is, of course, not fixed in steps.  It is proportional to the input voltage.

Sound is nothing but changes in air pressure relative to the listening device (like our ears or a microphone). The frequency and intensity of these variations define pitch and loudness. The microphone in an FM transmitter studio takes these variations and converts them into corresponding electrical signals of varying frequencies and intensities. These signals are passed to the modulator which changes its frequency accordingly.

One method is Direct Modulation, which involves feeding an audio signal (or any waveform you want) to a voltage-controlled oscillator.


but the question remain as VCOs also vary the frequency according to the intensity of the input signal.What if the input signal is also varying in frequency (ofcourse inside a range)?

Seemingly you think the frequency as a 100% independent dimension like the length of an object can be independent of the color of the object. It's not. The frequency can be calculated from how voltage, air pressure, field strength or other quantity varies during the time.
The frequency of a VCO follows the variations of the input voltage. Thus the VCO output contains also everything which is called the frequency of the input signal. If the input signal has a certain frequency that frequency becomes the variation rhythm of the VCO frequency.
